# Почему использовать сообщения об ошибках в коде может быть бесполезным?

Tags: c++, исключения, обработка-ошибок

1. > Теперь проверку должны осуществлять и вызываемая функция и вызывающие функции.

   Объясните пожалуйста что это значит, желательно, примером.
2. > Программист может забыть проверить аргументы в вызывающей функции, что приведет к непредсказуемым результатам.
   >
   > Вторая ситуация в которой проверка в вызывающем модуле не выполняется может легко привести к неожиданностям:
   >
   > ```
   > int f(int x, int y, int z)
   > {
   >     int area1 = area(x, y);
   >     if (area1 <= 0)
   >     {
   >         std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
   >     }
   >     int area2 = framedArea(1, z);
   >     int area3 = framedArea(y, z);
   >     double ratio = double(area1) / area3;
   >     // ...
   > }
   > ```
   >
   > Вы заметили ошибку? Такие ошибки трудно выявить так как сам код является правильным: ошибка заключается в том что программист не включил в него проверку.

   Я как раз таки вижу проверку. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться!

Comment: Код бессмысленен. `area`, `area3` и `ratio` не используются нигде и вся функция может быть сведена к одной строчке `{return framedArea(1, z);}`

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Это у ТС код бессмысленный, у Страуструпа там стоит вместо `return` - `//...`.

Comment: а причем тут что стоит у Страуструпа? Вопрос задается по приведенному коду...

Comment: теперь еще хуже: функция должна возвращать целое, но ничего не возвращает...

Answer (score 2):

Это из "Программирования" Страуструпа.

В 1 смысл в том, что при использовании сообщения об ошибке через возврат значения вызываемая функция проверяет, не произошла ли ошибка, и сообщает об этом вызывающей. В результате вызывающая обязана проверить, а что вернула вызываемая функция, не сообщила ли про ошибку. Т.е. проверка выполняется дважды (хотя и разная).

В примере вы не проверяете значения `area2` и `area3`. Вдруг они отрицательны или вообще `area3` равно нулю? Вот и пропустили... Да и значения аргументов тоже не проверяете (тут правда спорный вопрос, кто их должен проверять - вызывающая функция или вызываемая.

Кстати, у Страуструпа другой код - не вывод на экран сообщения, что все плохо, и продолжения работы, а вызов

```
if (area1<=0) error("Неположительная площадь");
```

т.е. программа на этом завершает работу, а не продолжает считать дальше.

Вот оригинал, откуда взят вопрос:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну и в каком месте такой код может получится бесполезным? Делать проверку несколько раз(в нескольких функциях) не делает использование сообщений об ошибках бесполезным.

Comment: Не столько бесполезным, сколько сложным, запутанным, а в сложных случаях - через три-четыре функции тянуть код ошибки - настолько сложным, что применять его просто не имеет смиысла. В С так и приходится жить, там другого механизма нет, но в С++ зачем?

Comment: то есть если например моя функция Ptr* find() возвращает нулевой указатель то мне лучше всегда прописывать в этой же функции выброс исключения?

Comment: Depends on. Вы вряд ли спрашиваете - каким горючим заправить машину, если у нее 4 колеса? зависит от машины. Как и ответ на ваш вопрпос зависит от того, что вы делаете, для чего и как...

Answer (score 1):

Представим себе такую ситуацию:(не будем придавать значение смыслу кода)

```
int area(int x, int y) { return x * y; }
int framedArea(int y, int z) { return y + z; }
int f(int x, int y, int z)
{
    int area1 = area(x, y);
    if (area1 <= 0)
    {
        std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
    }
    int area2 = framedArea(1, z);
    int area3 = framedArea(y, z);
    double ratio = double(area1 / area3);
    return ratio + area2;
}
void Foo(unsigned& a, int x, int y, int z) {    
    a = f(x, y, z);
}
```

Здесь `Foo` меняет значение обьекта беззнакового типа на значение, возвращаемое функцией  `f`. Я могу написать такую функцию, узнав, что функция `f` считает площади фигур по заданным координатам, а площади не имеют отрицательное значение. И, поэтому я в программе могу спокойно написать:

```
unsigned k = 4;
Foo(k, -3, 5, -3);
/*программа использует к, не подозревая, что он принял 
значение очень большое, так как
f(-3, 5, -3) возвращает отрицательное значение.
что с того, что я смогу в конце 
прочитать на консоли какое то сообщение? 
Может  мне консоль вообше не нужен в программе */
```

> Я забыл проверить аргументы в вызывающей функции

еще хуже, если я напишу программу долго и упорно, где то вызывая  `Foo(k, -3, 4, -4)` Программа в итоге будет иметь аварийное завершения из за деления на ноль в вызываемой функции.
Чтобы использовать `Foo`, я должен проверить все ли правильно с вызываемой функцией, хотя мне не должно интересовать код, написанный в ней....

> Теперь проверку должны осуществлять и вызываемая функция и вызывающие
>   функции.